# Doctrine 2 simple "bigger than" criteria

Tags: php, pdo, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In PDO / SQL i have a simple query with "bigger than":

```
DELETE * FROM tablexyz WHERE access > :old
```

Whats the equivalent in Doctrine 2 ORM?

I have already written a little code:

```
$criteria = ['access'=>$old];
$dataRepo = $entityManager->getRepository('tablexyz')->findBy($criteria)->delete();
```

My problem is, i want to use the bigger than operator in Doctrine 2 ORM but i don't want to make a function or class for that. Does somebody know a better or shorter solution for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either a query builder og just do a direct DQL (or SQL) query for it.

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('e')
   ->from('Entityxyz', 'e')
   ->where('e.access > :old')
   ->setParameter('old', $old);

$entities = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

or

```
$query = 'SELECT e FROM AppBundle\Entity\Entityxyz WHERE e.access > :old';

$entities = $entityManager->createQuery($query)
                          ->setParameter('old', $old)
                          ->getResult();`
```

---

I'd suggest you do create a repository method for it though, it's the correct place to have it. Using the query builder inside the repository is also simpler as it knows which entity you're referencing (and can skip calling select and from)

```
class EntityxyzRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getNewerThan($newerThan)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
        $qb->where('e.access > :newerThan')
           ->setParameter('newerThan', $newerThan);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the Functions of Doctrine like "findBy". A SQL Query in Doctrine ORM / DBAL is not what i want.

Comment: You can't, findBy is just for very simple comparisons. For more complex conditions you need to write your own methods